# Is there a way to calculate standard deviation and median for the models fitted using sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, gaussian-mixture-model

There is a method to return means of all the guassian components generated but I couldn't find any to get the standard deviations and the means.

Also, the means do not have any error component associated to them.

```
from scipy.stats import skewnorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

numValues = 10000
maxValue = 100
skewness = -5   
data = skewnorm.rvs(a = skewness,loc=maxValue, size=numValues) 

from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components = 1).fit(X=np.expand_dims(data,1))
```

The following would return the mean of the 1 component:

```
gmm.means_
```

> array([[99.21111667]])

Now, I would want to get the standard deviation as well as median of the model.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `median` parameter using `gmm`.

The parameter are the weights, means and covariance. Those information can be retrieve as follows:

```
gmm.weights_
gmm.means_
gmm.covariances_
```